# How to add unknown values in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a cash register program. My objective is for all the products be added and the final price be found. How can I reach this goal without knowing the values previously? Below is my code. Thanks in advance for any help it is greatly appreciated

```
responses = {}

polling_active = True

print("Welcome to the cash register. Insert your product name and price to be able to calculate your final total")


total = 0

while polling_active:
    product = input("\nProduct Name: ")
    total += float(input("Price: "))

    responses[product] = total

    repeat = input("Is this your final checkout? (Yes/No)")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = True
    elif repeat == 'No':
        polling_active = True
    elif repeat == 'Yes':
        polling_active = False
    elif repeat == 'yes':
        polling_active = False
    else:
        print("That operation is invalid")

print("\n---Final Checkout---")
for product, price in responses.items():
    print(product + " is $" + str(total))

print("\n---Total Price---")
print("Store Price is: ")
print("$" + str(total))

print("\n---Tax Price---")
print("Your price with tax is: ")

total = total * 1.13

print("$" + "{0:.2f}".format(float(total)))

print("\nThank you for shopping with us! Have a great day!")
```

I understand the with my current code, total will not allow me to add any products but that is just currently a place holder

Comment: So, you want to calculate the total without actually knowing the items prices?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. For example you could input 10 items or 5

Comment: It just needs to find the total cost of any amount

Comment: you may use `sum(responses.values())`

Comment: Where would I input that into the code

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that you need:

```
responses = {}

polling_active = True

print("Welcome to the cash register. Insert your product name and price to be able to calculate your final total")

while polling_active:
    product = input("\nProduct Name: ")
    price = float(input("Price: "))

    responses[str(product)] = price

    repeat = raw_input("Is this your final checkout? (Yes/No)")
    if repeat.lower() == 'no':
        polling_active = True
    elif repeat.lower() == 'yes':
        polling_active = False
    else:
        print("That operation is invalid")

print("\n---Final Checkout---")
for product, price in responses.items():
    print(product + " is $" + str(price))

print("\n---Total Price---")
print("Store Price is: ")
total= sum(responses.values())
print("$" + str(total))

print("\n---Tax Price---")
print("Your price with tax is: ")

total = total * 1.13

print("$" + "{0:.2f}".format(float(total)))

print("\nThank you for shopping with us! Have a great day!")
```

Output:

integer:
[image]

float:
[image]

Comment: How could I fix this? Otherwise it fixes the rest of the problem

Comment: Never mind I solved it. The error was when using floats (like 2.23 or 3.99) it didn't add them

Comment: alright, although i have made small changes in program like using `.lower()` and added float screenshot as well. Please upvote if i did what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have uprooted it and marked it as the answer. Thank you